# Can't run ec2 method in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I'm invoking the following lambda function to describe an instance information:

```
'use strict'

var aws = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var instanceID = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message).Trigger.Dimensions[0].value;

    aws.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    var ec2 = new aws.EC2;

    var params = {InstanceIds: [instanceID]};

    ec2.describeInstances(params, function(e, data) {
        if (e)
            console.log(e, e.stack);
        else
            console.log(data);
    }
};
```

In CloudWatch Logs I can see that function runs until the end, but doesn't log nothing inside ec2.describeInstances method:

END RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    Duration: xx ms Billed Duration: xx ms Memory Size: xx MB   Max Memory Used: xx MB

My lambda function has VPC access and IAM Role of AdministratorAccess (full access). For some reason, it can't run ec2.describeInstances method. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your EC2 instance in a Private subnet in a VPC?

Comment: Yes, and my lambda function has this subnet in its configuration.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue, and none of the answers helped

Comment: Hello. Check @error2007s answer. I resolved this by creating a subnet to NAT and a security group with outbound connections (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0). Both configured in the lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add VPC configuration to a Lambda function, it can only access resources in that VPC. If a Lambda function needs to access both VPC resources and the public Internet, the VPC needs to have a Network Address Translation (NAT) instance inside the VPC. So for that EC2 instance to send logs to cloud watch it needs internet connection through the NAT instance.

AWS Lambda uses the VPC information you provide to set up ENIs that allow your Lambda function to access VPC resources. Each ENI is assigned a private IP address from the IP address range within the Subnets you specify, but is not assigned any public IP addresses. Therefore, if your Lambda function requires Internet access (for example, to access AWS services that don't have VPC endpoints, such as Amazon Cloudwatch), you can configure a NAT instance inside your VPC or you can use the Amazon VPC NAT gateway. For more information, see [NAT Gateways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in the Amazon VPC User Guide. You cannot use an Internet gateway attached to your VPC, since that requires the ENI to have public IP addresses.

Comment: Instead of using an ec2 method and log it in CloudWatch, I want to use lambda function to ssh an ec2 instance inside same VPC of lambda configuration. Is it necessary to configure a NAT? Do I need to set a security group to allow lambda to connect to port 22 of the instance?

Comment: You can SSH into the instance no internet connection i.e NAT needed just for SSH. And yes you will require Lambda access to that EC2 insatnce

Answer (score 2):

First, try giving this [role](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#roles) to your Lambda

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
            "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
            "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction"
        ]
    }
```

If that doesn't make a difference then,

- you need to create an ENI. Go to the 'Network Interfaces' page https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home#NIC:sort=securityGroup and 'Create Network Interface'. Select the appropriate security groups and the subnet (say s0bn3t).
- Now, in the "Advanced Settings" of your Lambda, when you select the VPC, you will see a list of subnets. Now, select the subnet that the above ENI is associated with ('s0bn3t').

I believe this should do it.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue, and none of the answers helped